# How to convert accelerometer g force values to degrees

Tags: ios, accelerometer, core-motion

When using the `Core Motion` framework, I get values between 1 and -1 for `CMMotionManager`'s `accelerometerData` axis values.

If you hold the phone with the screen facing you and then rotate it 90 degrees left, you’ll get a -1g value in the `X` direction. Rotate it right, And you’ll see a 1g value.

I want these values to be represented as degrees, how can I make this conversion?

Comment: I fail to see any relation between those. 1g only mean 90 degrees depending on radius of the axis, speed, and for how long it's been rotating. I'm pretty sure your phone has other sensors you can use to determine that angle, like the compass.

Comment: 1g is just a force. it doesn't say anything about how LONG that force was applied for, and can't be used to give a direction. you can turn the phone 1 degree with 1g of force, or you can spin it completely around with 1g of force as well.

Comment: @MarcB the 1g is the force of gravity when the phone is at rest, it is not the force resulting from the turning motion, so it is constant.

Comment: @Paulw11: yes, but moving the phone will change that 1g. but until you know how LONG that change in force was applied, you cannot determine anything about position. if you're in a car accelerating at 1g, how fast are you going? impossible to say : how fast were you going originally, and how long have you been under 1g for?

Comment: You are under 1g "down" as long as you are on the planet Earth. When the phone isn't horizontal then the acceleration in the X axis becomes less than 1g  in the down direction as the sensor now isn't pointed directly to the earth. Some of that 1g is translated into the other sensors